# Creating curly braces with limits

Tags: math-mode, braces

[image]

Hello, I am trying to create curly braces with lower and upper limits to the right, as shown in the picture. I am unable to fix these limits on the braces. I am using `\bigl\{` and `\bigr\}` to create the braces.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me the standard way works. Have you tried this?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Thus, we get
\[
  \bigl\{\beta^w_{u_j}\bigr\}_{j=1}^n
\]
and
\[
  \bigl\{\beta^m_{u_j}\bigr\}_{j=1}^n
\]

In the same line:
\[
  \bigl\{\beta^w_{u_j}\bigr\}_{j=1}^n
  \quad\text{and}\quad
  \bigl\{\beta^m_{u_j}\bigr\}_{j=1}^n
\]

This is a long line, so that the equations are in the middle of two lines.
Everything in the same line using inline $\bigl\{\beta^w_{u_j}\bigr\}_{j=1}^n$
and $\bigl\{\beta^m_{u_j}\bigr\}_{j=1}^n$. But this doesn't look good, because
it might stretch the linespacing.

Using 
\[
  \text{Thus, we get}\quad%
  \bigl\{\beta^w_{u_j}\bigr\}_{j=1}^n
  \quad\text{and}\quad
  \bigl\{\beta^m_{u_j}\bigr\}_{j=1}^n
\]
does look better for the line spacing, but honestly it is not that pretty, imho.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works fine, however I have an additional question. When I form the two curly braces as you specified, the second brace automatically jumps to the next line. Is there a way I can have them both in the same line?`\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
Thus, we get \[ \bigl\{\beta^w_{u_j}\bigr\}_{j=1}^n\] and \[\bigl\{\beta^m_{u_j}\bigr\}_{j=1}^n\] \end{document}`

Comment: You do want the "and" and the second equation in the same line? If so, see my edit.

Comment: I actually wanted the initial 'Thus, we get' in the same line as well. Is that possible?

Comment: @KushaVerma now I listed almost every option. But I think only the first two look good.

Comment: why use display math here?  why not just `$...$`?  and if display math, why not use `gather*` and `\shortintertext` (requires `mathtools`)?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I provided an inline example. And I didn't use gather or `\shortintertex` because the initial question was just about the braces with limits. After that I included the options I think are commonly used. You might add those to the answer.